# How can I test a standalone watchOS application?

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, apple-watch-standalone

I can't figure out how to test running my watchOS app as a standalone app. When I run it on the simulator it never works unless I also have the associated iOS app. Running the watch scheme shows that the iOS app is running along with the watchOS app. I created a scheme which just builds the watch and it will cause the watch app to start, but it doesn't actually update the compiled binary.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you have to create certificates for all project targets and upload on Testflight, Through Testflight (mobile application) you can install the app and it will sync automatically in the watch.

The second option will, Connect your watch with mobile and install that watch application via Xcode on mobile, it will sync automatically in the watch.

Comment: Over time this bug doesn't effect me as much. Watch development is like rolling dice. Your answer is just about running an app, and not specific to Standalone Watch Apps.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky I am developing a standalone application for watchos 6 and i can install the application on my watch by the above two ways. i think you never tried that's why you downvoted my answer. first, you have to perform and then after conclude.